# Tortoise ORM create custom index. Problem with aerich migration

Tags: python, python-3.x, tortoise-orm

I create a custom index UniqueIndexWithCondition.
Run this command

```
aerich migrate --name initial_commit
```

response:

```
AttributeError: 'UniqueIndexWithCondition' object has no attribute 'index_name'
```

code example:
my custom index

```
class UniqueIndexWithCondition(Index):
    ...
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just redeclare a `index_name(self, *args, **kwargs)`